# halign=c appears to be not respected in tabularray

Tags: tables, tabularray

Consider the following code. The parameter halign=c appears to be not respected, as the image shows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {my caption},
    label = {tab:lab},
    ]{hlines, vlines,
        colspec = {X[1,cmd={\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}]},
        row{1} = {halign=c, font=\bfseries},
        rowhead = 1,
    }
    A   \\
    \lipsum[1-1][-2]
    
    \end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Could you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Well, `cmd={\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}` overwrites `halign=c`, I think, because it seems to be a "stronger" option. You could try `cmd={\centering}` instead of `halign=c`, but do you really need the `cmd` option here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cmd` option seems to be stronger than the `halign` option and thus overwrites it. If you want to use `\RaggedRight`, you should maybe rather try the solution proposed in the [`tabularray` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) (section 6.1: "Control Horizontal Alignment") and redefine `\TblrAlignLeft` which is used to set the alignment of `l` columns:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\RenewDocumentCommand\TblrAlignLeft{}{\RaggedRight}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {my caption},
        label = {tab:lab},
    ]{
        hlines, vlines,
        colspec = {X[l]},
        row{1} = {c, font=\bfseries},
        rowhead = 1,
    }
    A  \\
    \lipsum[1-1][-2]
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works really fine! Thanks, @JasperHabicht!